# Implementing SPF for a mail server that sends email on its own, with GoDaddy

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, spf, godaddy, dmarc

I have some troubles configuring SPF/DKIM for a VPS with a running instance of Postfix. Thanks to DMARC reports I'm finding and fixing always more issues.

Today I have a problem by setting SPF records in GoDaddy for a subdomain that matches the machine's name.

Given that domain is `mydomain.com` and the host with mailserver is `host.mydomain.com`.
On my GoDaddy DNS panel, `host.mydomain.com` is a CNAME to `somehostname.cloudapp.net`.

When I try to add a SPF record for the subdomain `@host.mydomain.com` I get an error that there is already a `host` CNAME record and I can't create a `host` TXT record. The `@` record for `mydomain.com` is up and running, and all DMARC reports are fine with that.

The question is: how can I tell GoDaddy to create a `host.mydomain.com` TXT record on DNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CNAME records can't coexist with other types of records, including TXT ones.

Comment: Accepted becaue it's a brief and clear explanation of how DNS works. Any alternative?

Comment: Some DNS providers have a system where they can have a record pose as an A record while being essentially a CNAME behind the scenes - Amazon Route53 calls them ALIAS records, for example.